# Building array for data input from checkbox in MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, razor, checkbox

I'm probably doing this all wrong, but it is partially working so I am hoping it is my lack of knowledge of the correct syntax.

I am building a checkbox array from a linq query which is working fine. Then I check to see if the Answer has a value matching a checkbox value. So far so good, BUT it will not create an array to input into the database, it just returns the value of the first checked box.

Can you spot an error in my syntax? I am very new to Razor and tend to stick to the HTML I know, rather than helpers. I will learn them - in time!

```
//    Checkbox
  <div class="checkbox">
  @foreach (var item in q.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
     {
      if (q.Answer == item.QuestionOption1)
      {
       <input type="checkbox" name="Answer" id="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" checked />@item.QuestionOption1<br />
        **q.Answer = q.Answer + "," + item.QuestionOption1;**
      }
      else
      {
       <input type="checkbox" name="Answer" id="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" />@item.QuestionOption1<br />
      }
     }
</div>
```

The q.Answer statement is doing nothing at all. How should I code it, please?

And the model;

```
namespace Template.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class QuestionOption
   {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionOption1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionOptionRanking { get; set; }

    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd change the `id` for every `item`. I don't know if that's the root of your problem, but I would suggest you first generate unique ids for all your check-boxes.

Comment: Is there a chance of an example? Someone posted code and I tried it but its not working, and new the example is gone! Not sure what happened there; but it didn't work anyway.

Comment: That was me but I misunderstood your question so I deleted my (wrong) answer. You should post your model definition (i.e. `QuestionOptions`) so that we have information to build upon.

Comment: If you try to bind the posted value to `QuestionOption` model, there should be property with name `answer`. Also, it should be `list` and name generated in the `view` should be  `[0].answer`,`[1].answer`.....

Comment: But answer is not always a list; in the other 3 conditions it is a single string. Maybe I am trying to do too much in one action and should split the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give unique name for each checkbox. Try like following.

```
 @{
  int count=1;
  string name="Answer"+1;
  foreach (var item in q.QuestionOptions.OrderBy(o => o.QuestionOptionRanking))
 {
  if (q.Answer == item.QuestionOption1)
  {
   <input type="checkbox" name=@name id="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" checked />@item.QuestionOption1<br />
    **q.Answer = q.Answer + "," + item.QuestionOption1;**
  }
  else
  {
   <input type="checkbox" name=@name id="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" />@item.QuestionOption1<br />
  }
  count++;
 }
}
```

Comment: I have set so many breakpoints - but it does not seem to hit the q.answer = q.Answer... statement before input. It is just returning null. Should I move the line to the input model instead?

Answer (score 0):

MVC follows name attribute for model binding, you must declare all the checkbox with different name attribute value.

[How to post a list with MVC Model binding](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Say

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="QuestionOptions[0]" id="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" checked />@item.QuestionOption1<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="QuestionOptions[1]" id="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" checked />@item.QuestionOption1<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="QuestionOptions[2]" id="Answer" value="@item.QuestionOption1" checked />@item.QuestionOption1<br />
```

Comment: I have tried this using Azim's suggestion, but it is returning null. Please see my comment to his answer.